# Websphere App Server - DCSV0002W - Migration issues

Tags: java, websphere, application-server

i'm having some issues after a migration to HA enviroments, the Sysout Log is showing the following problem

> [3/31/13 11:15:17:096 CLT] 00000004 QueueTHandler W   DCSV0002W: DCS Stack DefaultCoreGroup at Member lnxq030Cell01\lnxq060Node01\ibra01: An unexpected internal programming state has occurred. Internal details:  "Can't open Async QueueT because DCS got null member address from the AddressResolver" {Method=QueueTHandler.openQTonIpPort(), PtpRmmNode=PtpRmmNode|lnxq030Cell01\ibra01\riesgoCred01|null|2, TopicName=[B@29442944} . The exception is .

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you completed all the WAS configuration that your application(s) needs? It doesn't seem like much info to go off of but, it kind of looks like WAS is having a problem connecting to some URL. Is there a firewall in the way of any other servers it needs to talk to?

Comment: Everything is checked, it's only happening for High Availability

Answer (score 0):

I met the issue recently, and finally I found the problem is from my mistake:

`manageProfile.bat -create ... -hostName xxx`

We should not use the argument -hostName, defaultly the command will use the full qualified host name.
The correct command should be:

`manageProfile.bat -create ... -dmgrHost xxx`